# Merge two DataFrames with some equal columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have two csv files:

1.csv

```
id,noteId,text
id2,idNote19,This is my old text 2
id5,idNote13,This is my old text 5
id1,idNote12,This is my old text 1
id3,idNote10,This is my old text 3
id4,idNote11,This is my old text 4
```

2.csv

```
id,noteId,text,other
id3,idNote10,new text 3,On1
id2,idNote19,My new text 2,Pre8
```

Loading them like:

```
>>> df1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv', encoding='utf-8').set_index('id')
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv', encoding='utf-8').set_index('id')
>>>
>>> print df1
       noteId                   text
id
id2  idNote19  This is my old text 2
id5  idNote13  This is my old text 5
id1  idNote12  This is my old text 1
id3  idNote10  This is my old text 3
id4  idNote11  This is my old text 4
>>> print df2
        noteId            text other
id
id3   idNote10      new text 3   On1
id2   idNote19   My new text 2  Pre8
id5        NaN   My new text 2   Hl0
id22  idNote22  My new text 22    M1
```

I need merge both DataFrames in something like this (ovewriting values on df1 that are empty on df2, adding extra columns and rows that not exists on df1):

```
        noteId                   text other
id
id2   idNote19          My new text 2  Pre8
id5        NaN          My new text 2   Hl0
id1   idNote12  This is my old text 1   NaN
id3   idNote10             new text 3   On1
id4   idNote11  This is my old text 4   NaN
id22  idNote22         My new text 22    M1
```

### **My real DataFrames has other columns that should be merged too, not just `text`**

I tried using `merge` getting something like:

```
>>> df1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv', encoding='utf-8')
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv', encoding='utf-8')
>>>
>>> print df1
    id    noteId                   text
0  id2  idNote19  This is my old text 2
1  id5  idNote13  This is my old text 5
2  id1  idNote12  This is my old text 1
3  id3  idNote10  This is my old text 3
4  id4  idNote11  This is my old text 4
>>> print df2
    id    noteId           text
0  id3  idNote10     new text 3
1  id2  idNote19  My new text 2
>>>
>>> print merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['id'])
    id  noteId_x                 text_x  noteId_y         text_y
0  id2  idNote19  This is my old text 2  idNote19  My new text 2
1  id5  idNote13  This is my old text 5       NaN            NaN
2  id1  idNote12  This is my old text 1       NaN            NaN
3  id3  idNote10  This is my old text 3  idNote10     new text 3
4  id4  idNote11  This is my old text 4       NaN            NaN
>>>
```

**But it's not what I need. I don't know if I'm on the right path and should merge the suffixed columns or if there is a better way to do this.**

Thanks!

**Update:**
Added ovewriting values on df1 that are empty on df2, adding extra columns on df2 that should be present on df1 after "merge" and rows that should be appended on df1

--

## SOLUTION

Based on a @U2EF1 (thanks!) comment, I found the solution:

```
df1.fillna(value='None', inplace=True)
df2.fillna(value='None', inplace=True)

concat([df1, df2]).groupby('id').last().fillna(value='None')
```

*In my case, it's very important to define a default "empty" value, that's why the `fillna`.*

Comment: You have different values in both columns `text` - which value you need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you can solve this with the proper index:

```
df1.set_index(['id', 'noteId'], inplace=True)
df1.update(df2)
```

(And if you don't want that index after, just `df1.reset_index(inplace=True)`)

Comment: `noteId` is not an index in this case, could be any column. But the `update` method is very close to what I need. The only problem with this solution is that `update` won't add new rows on `df2`, won't overwrite empty values on `df2` and extra columns on `df2` won't be added either on `df1`. Is there any other "magic" method? :)

Comment: @inakiabt You can always concatenate and use a groupby with the function `last`.

Comment: Can you post an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Edited to update add rows,columns and update data, Efficiently merging on the Indexes**

Code to update your df1 with df2 data...

```
    df1 = """id,noteId,text
id2,idNote19,This is my old text 2
id5,idNote13,This is my old text 5
id1,idNote12,This is my old text 1
id3,idNote10,This is my old text 3
id4,idNote11,This is my old text 4"""

df2 ="""id,noteId,text,other
id3,idNote10,My new text 3,On1
id2,idNote19,My new text 2,Pre8
id5,NaN,My new text 2,Hl0
id22,idNote22,My new text 22,M1"""


df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(df1),sep=",",index_col='id')#this is how you should
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(df2),sep=",",index_col='id')#set your index in read_csv not after
```

## **SOLUTION**

```
df = pd.merge(df2,df1,how='outer',on=df1.columns.tolist(),left_index=True,right_index=True)
#joined on indexes for speed
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>print df

        noteId                   text other
id                                         
id1   idNote12  This is my old text 1   NaN
id2   idNote19          My new text 2  Pre8
id22  idNote22         My new text 22    M1
id3   idNote10             new text 3   On1
id4   idNote11  This is my old text 4   NaN
id5        NaN          My new text 2   Hl0
```

**Reason it works...**

pd.merge has a couple of multipurpose params.  The on key actually is actually only used to join the two dataframes when the left_index and right_index keys are set to False - the default value.  Otherwise it will just join the identically named columns that are found from the on value. In this case the two columns 'text' and 'noteId'. (I made it a more general by using df1.columns.tolist() as the param - this means any identically named columns in df2 will overwrite the data from df1 instead of marking it text_y)

Using the more general on key (df1.values.tolist()) you can actually loop through a bunch of csvs updating the data from the dataframe as you go

### **3X faster than accepted solution**

```
In [25]: %timeit       pd.merge(df2,df1,how='outer',on=df1.columns.tolist(),left_index=True,right_index=True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 ms per loop
```

**accepted solution**

```
In [30]: %timeit pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('noteId').last().fillna(value='None')
100 loops, best of 3: 3.29 ms per loop
```

Comment: It works with `df1.loc[df2.indexes, "text"] = df2["text"]`. I should do this for each column on `df2`. What about the performance of this solution if `df2` is "big" (+100K rows)?

Comment: Should still be fast but to speed it up try using the indexes...  df1.index.isin(df2.index).  Not positive but this could speed it up.  Let me know if it does or if you find a faster solution

Comment: I've updated the question. I forgot to mention that `df2` could have extra columns that not exists on `df1` and should be "merged" too.

Comment: Hi I looked at the update solution which should've worked but update only supports left merges.  I dug a little deeper into the capabilities of merge and found the solution.

Comment: You should check out my answer, I feel it is cleaner and I've found it to be 3 times faster than what you are using

Comment: Can you send me an email to {myusername} at gmail?

Comment: instead of that lets just use the chat feature...  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57521/inakiabt-zjs